# How to get all the rows from spark DataFrame?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

```
scala> val results = spark.sql("select _c1, count(1) from data group by _c1 order by count(*) desc")
results: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [_c1: string, count(1): bigint]

scala> results.persist()
res18: results.type = [_c1: string, count(1): bigint]

scala> results.show(20, false)
```

This code gets only the top 20 rows. How can I get the full list of rows? Any help would be appreciated [image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can just use `count` function to *get total row count* and use it in `show` function as

```
results.show(results.count.toInt, false)
```